# How do I access/edit pixels from a captured image C#

Tags: c#, camera, win-universal-app

I am trying to apply my own custom effect to a picture so I need to be able to access the individual pixels of an image. Using MediaCapture I can get a CapturedPhoto.Frame as a stream or softwarebitmap but I am unable to find how I can edit them.

```
//initialize mediacapture with default camera
var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

//create low lag capture and take photo
var lowLagCapture = await mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaPixelFormat.Bgra8));
var capturedPhoto = await lowLagCapture.CaptureAsync();

capturedPhoto.Frame.AsStream()
capturedPhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the pixels of an image you can use a SoftwareBitmap. To access pixels in the RGB color space you can use the Bgra8 color format. To convert to Bgra8 use

```
var softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(capturedPhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
```

To get access to the bytes of the image you need to initialize the IMemoryBufferByteAccess COM interface by adding the following code within your namespace

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("5B0D3235-4DBA-4D44-865E-8F1D0E4FD04D")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
    void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}
```

Next you will need to set the unsafe compiler flag. Right Click Project -> Properties -> Build -> check allow unsafe code.

Now you can access/edit pixels directly as shown below.

```
public unsafe void editSoftwarebitmap(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap)
{
    //create buffer
    using (BitmapBuffer buffer = softwareBitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Write))
    {
        using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
        {
            byte* dataInBytes;
            uint capacity;
            ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacity);

            //fill-in the BGRA plane
            BitmapPlaneDescription bufferLayout = buffer.GetPlaneDescription(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < bufferLayout.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bufferLayout.Width; j++)
                {
                    //get offset of the current pixel
                    var pixelStart = bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j;

                    //get gradient value to set for blue green and red
                    byte value = (byte)((float)j / bufferLayout.Width * 255);
                    dataInBytes[pixelStart + 0] = value; //Blue
                    dataInBytes[pixelStart + 1] = value; //Green
                    dataInBytes[pixelStart + 2] = value; //Red
                    dataInBytes[pixelStart + 3] = (byte)255; //Alpha
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Imaging How-To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging) for more documentation.

Comment: sorry but could you explain this: dataInBytes and could we get the pointer address of that image (the start byte of that image for editing)